# OnPaint font color

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I'm using the OnPaint method for some drawing issues. At this point, I added to the OnPaint method the following code:

```
CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
dc.SetDCBrushColor(RGB(100,0,0));
dc.SetDCPenColor(RGB(100,0,0));
dc.DrawText("My text", CRect(0,0,200,200), DT_SINGLELINE | DT_TOP | DT_CENTER);
CDialogEx::OnPaint();
```

But what I have is a black "My text" instead of a red one.

How can I effective change the color of that text ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used the

```
SetTextColor(dc,RGB(100,0,0));
```

before the

```
dc.DrawText(...);
```

and works fine

Comment: What is said on  https://books.google.pt/books?id=lt9660Apj8EC&pg=PA180&lpg=PA180&dq=settextcolor+drawtext&source=bl&ots=F2IA8HYqms&sig=f4fFx_ttk_ZFzZ6Y3f6QlkvKOdQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=settextcolor%20drawtext&f=false

confirms the answer.